# Stream not returning any value

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a stream that apparently does not return a value. Instead of returning anything, the snapshot I use in my Streambuilder returns the yellow container (see code below) which is returned when my snapshot has no data. Any idea what causes this issue?

Below you will all functions, the stream as well as my Streambuilder.

Here is the updated stream. The otherUserId print statement is NOT printed. Maybe the error lies somewhere here.

```
Stream<List>? roomsListStream() async* {
try {
  print("userId: $userId");
  var rooms = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("rooms")
      .where("users", arrayContains: userId)
      .orderBy("latestMessageTime", descending: true)
      .snapshots();
  rooms.map((QuerySnapshot query) {
    List<RoomsListModel> retVal = [];
    for (var element in query.docs) {
      // get other user id
      String otherUserId = element["users"][0] == userId
          ? element["users"][1]
          : element["users"][0];
      print("otherUserId: $otherUserId");
      // get other user details
      getOtherUser(otherUserId).then((value) {
        retVal.add(RoomsListModel(
            roomId: element.id,
            otherUserId: otherUserId,
            avatar: value["photoUrl"],
            name: value["name"],
            lastMessage: element["latestMessage"],
            lastMessageTime: element["latestMessageTime"]));
      });
    }
    print(retVal);
    return retVal;
  });
} catch (e) {
  print("Error: $e");
}
```

}

```
  import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:blabber_tech/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:blabber_tech/services/chat_services.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'package:blabber_tech/models/room_model.dart';

// Rooms List Model
class RoomsListModel {
  String roomId;
  String otherUserId;
  String avatar;
  String name;
  String lastMessage;
  Timestamp lastMessageTime;

  RoomsListModel(
      {required this.roomId,
      required this.otherUserId,
      required this.avatar,
      required this.name,
      required this.lastMessage,
      required this.lastMessageTime});
}

class MyChatsScreen3 extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = "mychats3_screen";

  @override
  State<MyChatsScreen3> createState() => _MyChatsScreenState();
}

// get other user details
Future getOtherUser(String id) async {
  // get other user profile
  var user = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(id)
      .get()
      .then((value) => value.data()) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  // return other user profile
  return user;
}

class _MyChatsScreenState extends State<MyChatsScreen3> {
  // get current user id
  String userId = AuthService().getUserId();

  // get all active chats
  **Stream<List>? roomsListStream() {**
    try {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("rooms")
          .where("users", arrayContains: userId)
          .orderBy("latestMessageTime", descending: true)
          .snapshots()
          .map((QuerySnapshot query) {
        List<RoomsListModel> retVal = [];
        query.docs.forEach((element) {
          retVal.add(RoomsListModel(
              roomId: element.id,
              otherUserId: element["users"][0] == userId
                  ? element["users"][1]
                  : element["users"][0],
              avatar: element["photoUrl"],
              name: element["name"],
              lastMessage: element["latestMessage"],
              **lastMessageTime: element["latestMessageTime"]**));
        });

        return retVal;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
    }
  }

// List builder for mobile app
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        // create listview of all chats of current user and show last message and other user name and photo
        child: **StreamBuilder(**
          stream: roomsListStream(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
            **if (snapshot.hasData) {**
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                        // show other user profile photo
                        //backgroundImage:
                        //NetworkImage(otherUser["profilePhotoUrl"]),
                        ),
                    //title: Text(snapshot.data[index]["userName"]),
                    subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index]["lastMessage"]),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else {
              return Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to `await` for `FirebaseFirestore` result:

```
Stream<List>? roomsListStream() async* {
    try {
      var rooms = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("rooms")
          .where("users", arrayContains: userId)
          .orderBy("latestMessageTime", descending: true)
          .snapshots();

      await rooms.map((QuerySnapshot query) async*{
        List<RoomsListModel> retVal = [];
        query.docs.forEach((element) {
          retVal.add(RoomsListModel(
              roomId: element.id,
              otherUserId: element["users"][0] == userId
                  ? element["users"][1]
                  : element["users"][0],
              avatar: element["photoUrl"],
              name: element["name"],
              lastMessage: element["latestMessage"],
              lastMessageTime: element["latestMessageTime"]));
        });

        yield retVal;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
    }
  }
```

and also change this:

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
```

to this:

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData) {
```

Comment: When I do that, I need to add async to my function and make it a future. But when I do that, I get this error in my StreamBuilder: "The argument type 'Future<Stream<List<dynamic>>?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<dynamic>?'."

Comment: The changes work now. But I still just get returned the yellow container instead of anything below the if(snapshot.hasData)

Comment: I rollback my answer to previous one, you can use `async*` instead of `async`.

Comment: Thank you! But it still only returns the yellow container :/

Comment: I have added an update above. I updated the stream code (it still does not work) and it does not print one print statement.

Comment: you need yield instead of return.

Comment: When I do that it says: Undefined class 'yield'. (Documentation)  Try changing the name to the name of an existing class, or creating a class with the name 'yield'

Comment: And also: The name 'retVal' is already defined

Comment: My bad sorry, check the new update.

Comment: Thank you! But it still just returns the yellow container. I printed the snapshot data and it returns null...no clue why

Comment: I changed the if statement now as well and it still does not work. Can you kindly check in my post the print statement I added in the stream? "otherUserId" is not getting printed, I think the mistake is somewhere there

Comment: did you add await rooms.map((QuerySnapshot query) async*{?

Comment: Yes added it already^^

Comment: Last try, change your `map` to this: `await rooms.forEach((QuerySnapshot query) async*{`

Comment: Does not solve it sadly. But thank you a lot for taking the time and for the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249331/discussion-between-cipano-and-eamirho3ein).